# Compile an .Rnw with greek text to pdf

Tags: windows, r, pdf, sweave, miktex

I tried it using the commented out code without success. Can somebody help?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}


%\latintext 
\title{Sweave Example 1}
\author{George Dontas}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

In this example we embed parts of the examples from the
\texttt{kruskal.test} help page into a \LaTeX{} document:

%\greektext 
Αυτό είναι κείμενο στα Ελληνικά
%\latintext
<<eval=TRUE,echo=TRUE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,error=FALSE>>=
data(airquality)

kruskal.test(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality)
@

which shows that the location parameter of the Ozone distribution varies significantly from month to month. Finally we
include a boxplot of the data:

\begin{center}
<<eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,results='hide',warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,error=FALSE>>=
boxplot(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality)
@
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It might be useful if you add the error message you get into your post.

Comment: if the Sweave process works fine and  the failure occurs in the processing from (La)TeX to PDF, this question would probably be more appropriate at http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not the R but matter of getting latex to play well with Greek.  With hat tip to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24728/xelatex-with-polyglossia-and-greek), perhaps the easiest solution is to switch to XeLaTeX compilation and rewrite your file as

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{greek}

\title{Sweave Example 1}
\author{George Dontas}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Ελληνικό κείμενο

In this example we embed parts of the examples from the
\texttt{kruskal.test} help page into a \LaTeX{} document:

...
```

and so on as before.  Then compile with XeLaTeX (`latexmk -xelatex file.Rnw` will do that).

Comment: Thank you! I get the error:  The font "Linux Libertine O" cannot be found.

Comment: Hmm.. I changed font to Arial and saved the .rnw using uTF-8 encoding and it worked.

Comment: Ah, that font must have been one of mine. Still, glad it worked.

Comment: However, greek text inside R plots (e.g. a plot title in greek) does not appear correctly.  Any ideas?

Comment: Adding "dev='cairo_pdf'" in chunk options solves the problem!

Comment: You're way ahead of me here. Is there a good page or blog that covers on latex/greek issues? (Preferably in english or german).  It would be handy to have all these things in one place.

Comment: I don't know. I found that solution by googling: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/436